# Ruby on Rails - nested associations - creating new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

I'm learning Rails (4.2 installed) and working on a social network simulation application.
I have setup an one to many relation between Users and Posts and now I'm trying to add also Comments to posts. After multiple tries and following the [documentation on rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) I ended up with the following setup:

**User Model**

```
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
```

**Post Model**

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
```

**Comment Model**

```
  belongs_to :user
```

The comment is initiated from the Post show page, so the
**Post Controller** has:

```
def show
    @comment = Comment.new
  end
```

Now the question is: in **Comments Controller** , what is the correct way to create a new record.
I tried the below and many others, but without success.

```
def create

    @comment = current_user.posts.comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.save

    redirect_to users_path

  end
```

(current_user is from Devise)

Also, afterwards, how can I select the post corresponding to a comment?

Thank you

Comment: `current_user.posts` is a collection of posts. The `has_many` association is on a single post, not a collection of them. (Edit: I should have submitted as answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create a relation on `Post`, letting each `Comment` know "which `Post` it relates to."  In your case, you'll likely want to create a foreign key on `Comment` for `post_id`, then each `Comment` will `belong_to` a specific `Post`.  So, you'd add `belongs_to :post` on your `Comment` model.

So, your models become:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Then, to create a `Comment`, you would want to do one of two things in your controller:

1. Load the `Post` corresponding to the `Comment` you are creating via the URI as a parameter.
2. Pass the `Post` ID along in the form in which calls the `create` method on `Comment`.

I personally prefer loading the `Post` from a parameter in the URI, as you'll have less checking to do as far as authorization for can the `Comment` in question be added to the `Post` - e.g. think of someone hacking the form and changing the ID for the `Post` that the form originally sets.

Then, your `create` method in the `CommentsController` would look like this:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(post_id_param)

  # You'll want authorization logic here for
  # "can the current_user create a Comment
  # for this Post", and perhaps "is there a current_user?"

  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)

  if @comment.save
    redirect_to posts_path(@post)
  else
    # Display errors and return to the comment
    @errors = @comment.errors
    render :new
  end
end


private

def post_id_param
  params.require(:post_id)
end

def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(...) # permit acceptable Comment params here
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! really detailed and professional answer. 
Just to see if I got this right:

1. Is that the correct way to pass the param in the URL using simple_form?
`simple_form_for(@comment, url: comments_path(@comment, post_id: @post.id)) do |f|`
2. in CommentsController, before @comment.save, I had to add the user, otherwise won't save. Is that correct?

`@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
@comment.user = current_user `

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.  I haven't used simple_form, but I believe that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Comment` model into:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user, through: :post
end
```

Pass the `post_id` from view template:

`<%= hidden_field_tag 'post_id', @post.id %>`

Then change your `create` action:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```